# How to copy files to destination system through a specific LAN card?

Tags: ip, local-area-network, ssis, xcopy, files

I want to copy database backup from my running DB Server to Backup server. The source server has two LAN cards connected through their own IP address. One LAN card is used to connect to the application server and I want to user the other LAN card to transfer the backup to the backup server so that it may not affect the performance of running applications.

I cannot run any job on destination server to pull the data from the source server and all the job have to run from source server. Could anyone inform me if there is any way to specify the specific IP address of source server through which I can copy the backup to the backup server?

Any solution like SSIS or Batch file will work.

Comment: Are these IP addresses on the same or different subnetworks?

Answer (score 2):

Solution to your problem is to use different subnet for the second interface than the interface used to connect the application server. So that both the communications i.e source to application server and source to database server will be isolated from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source server is Windows, you could add a static route to the backup server via the second interface. example interface A 192.168.1.10, Interface B (for backups) 192.168.1.11.  Backup server 192.168.1.50

from an elevated command prompt, type route print and take note of the Interface List at the top of the output. Identify the interface on which you want the traffic to leave so that it can replace the 'XX' in the command below:

route add -p 192.168.1.50 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.11 IF 'XX'